# How to get the active tab window function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a google **chrome extension**. I need to get the active tab window function. and update the window function. But can't get the active tab window function.

```
 chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabs[0].id! },
        function: () => {
          console.log(window);
        }
      })
      });
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Dummy Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an Extension with Angular",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab",
      "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Chrome extension",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://localhost:8004/*",
    "https://localhost:8004/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: No one can answer unless you post manifest.json, html and javascript.

Comment: I added manifest.json.

Comment: I can't answer as you don't post html and javascript.

Comment: @jobayer 1) Where is your JS code located, in background.js or the popup (probably "index.js")? 2) Are there any error messages? 3) Why do you want to update the window function? I'm asking because your question sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Remove `!` from code.